# How to call base overloaded method in c#?

Tags: c#

I have the following class hierarchy

```
class A
{
    public virtual string M()
    {
        return M(String.Empty);
    }

    public virtual string M(string s)
    {
        return M(s, false);
    }

    public virtual string M(string s, bool flag)
    {
        // Some base logic here
    }
}

class B:A
{
    public override string M(string s, bool flag)
    {
        string baseResult = base.M(s);

        // Derived class logic here
    }
}
```

The class B can be used in two cases:

1)

```
A b = new B();
string result = b.M();
```

2)

```
B b2 = new B();
string result2 = b2.M(someString, true);
```

Both cases crash with StackOverflowException. This happens because base.M(s) which is called inside B.M(string s, bool flag) will call B.M(string s, bool flag) again.

Is there any good way to avoid this?

I understand that if I call base.M(s, flag) everything will work, but what if someone else develops a dervived class and access base.M(s) ? I don't like to leave a possibility of StackOverflowException here.

**SOLUTION**

Now my hierarchy will look like

```
class A
{
    public string M()
    {
        return M(String.Empty, false);
    }

    public virtual string M(string s, bool flag)
    {
        // Some base logic here
    }
}

class B:A
{
    public override string M(string s, bool flag)
    {
        string baseResult = base.M(s, flag);

        // Derived class logic here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually the trick here is to have **one** `virtual` (usually the one with most parameters), and this is the only one you call vertically. The others might be non-virtual and just call the "main" one with appropriate defaults.

Comment: I agree with Marc. In addition, if you're thinking about providing overloaded methods in your descendant classes be aware that this could end up confusing consumers of your class. Take a look at this chapter from More Effective C#, titled Avoid Overloading Methods Defined in Base Classes  http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1570631

Comment: Oh, I see. I think I should get rid of unnecessary complexity here.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with something like this:

```
class A
{
    public virtual string M(string s = "", bool flag = false)
    {
        // Some base logic here
    }
}
```

instead of having 3 overloaded methods which all end up calling the same method with hard-coded parameters.

Comment: That's no good if OP is working with an older edition of the language, but it's probably the way to go with C# 4.0.

Comment: Worth noting that this is only valid for C#/.NET4

Comment: That would be great, but unfortunately I'm not targeting only C#4.0

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really do this, but sometimes when you need a cheap 'hacky' solution you can do the following:

```
public interface IFooBar
{
    void DoSomething(Object obj);
}

public class Foo
{
    public virtual void DoSomething(Object input)
    {
        this.DoSomething(input, false);
    }

    protected virtual void DoSomething(Object input, bool skipSomeBits)
    {
        //Does stuff for Foo and Bar
        if (!skipSomeBits)
        {
            //Does stuff that is specific to Foo but does not need to happen to Bar
        }
    }
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    public override void DoSomething(object input)
    {
        base.DoSomething(input, true);
    }
}
```

Or (This one is more appropriate than above) you can create virtual method that for child (`Bar`) is empty and does not call `base` but for parent (`Foo`) it does things:

```
public interface IFooBar
{
    void DoSomething(Object obj);
}

public class Foo
{
    public virtual void DoSomething(Object input)
    {
        //Does Foo and Bar stuff
        this.DoSomething2(input);
    }

    protected virtual void DoSomething2(Object input)
    {
        //Does Foo stuff
    }

}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    protected override void DoSomething2(Object input)
    {
        //Does not call base.DoSomething2() therefore does nothing or can do Bar stuff if needs be...
    }
}
```